# MongoDB: invalid ObjectId, ObjectId.id must be either a string or a Buffer, but is [{"type":"Buffer","data":[]}]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am currently struggling to find a document with mongodb. I tried several things but can't understand the root issue or find any helpful information. I want to search for the following document:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f97f73270f9d39dc29c7a6f"},"name":"XXX","surname":"XXX","position":"XXX"}
```

I currently have the id as a string, but obviously have an ObjectId in the mongodb collection. I googled around and found calls like

```
collection.find({ _id: new ObjectId("5f97f73270f9d39dc29c7a6f")})
```

multiple times, however this just seems to not work as I receive the following error upon execution

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid ObjectId, ObjectId.id must be either a string or a Buffer, but is [{"type":"Buffer","data":[]}]
```

I tried ObjectId from mongoose and mongodb. However, with `{ _id: { $oid: "5f97f73270f9d39dc29c7a6f" }}` the query works just fine. Also it would work with the ObjectId object directly returned from a find query. I hope someone got any explanation why it would not work with the mongodb/mongoose ObjectIds.

Comment: With Mongoose you can just do `Model.findById("5f97f73270f9d39dc29c7a6f")`, which is an alias to `Model.findOne({_id : "5f97f73270f9d39dc29c7a6f"})`. Your error message says it all : `ObjectId.id must be either a string or a buffer`, so just give it a string.

Comment: @JeremyThille By using only string,  I am also not able to find the desired document.

Comment: Well you should :) Because I do it every day with this syntax, as explained in [Mongoose's documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Comment: Maybe I missed out on some important information. We are talking about frontend here with Mongo's Realm Web SDK. So using mongoose functions are out of scope here. But still {_id : "5f97f73270f9d39dc29c7a6f"} does not work.

Comment: Ah, this is taking me off-guard, I have never heard of Realm Web SDK. But anyway, how can MongoDB even run in the front-end? I got completely lost suddenly